# Ruby having trouble sorting hash within array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hashtable

I have a data model that returns the following array:

`[[54993, {:posted_at=>1363066554, :item_id=>55007,..}],..]`

The `54993` is the post_id. I'm trying to take this array and sort by `posted_at`. The array comes sorted correctly by `posted_at`. Here's my current code:

```
  post_ids = UserFeed.new(current_user.id).posts.collect{|x| x[0]}
  posts = Post.where(:id => post_ids)
```

This sorts it by `post_id`, not `posted_at`. I'm trying to figure out how to sort by `posted_at`, and wondering why the array resorts by `post_id`.

Comment: is this activerecord? in any case, tag it accordingly. If so, I fail to see how a "posts" association can return pairs. In AR, when the associations are properly configured, you show be able to write `posts = UserFeed.new(current_user.id).posts.order("posted_at ASC")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where(ids)` does not set order, it uses a SQL `IN (id1, id2, ...)`. With ActiveRecord:

```
post_ids = UserFeed.new(current_user.id).posts.map(&:first)
posts = Post.where(:id => post_ids).order("posted_at ASC")
```

If there is no attribute `posts.posted_at`, then, solution 1:

```
posts = post_ids.map { |post_id| Post.find(post_id) }
```

Solution 2: this performs a single query and then sorts:

```
indexes = Hash[post_ids.map.with_index.to_a]
posts = Post.where(:id => post_ids).sort_by { |p| indexes[p.id] }
```

Comment: BOOM! This answer is so full of win. Your second suggestion was correct; I forgot to mention in the question that `posted_at` is not a saved attribute of posts. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you really need that array in memory instead of sorting your data using a DB query, try this:

```
method_that_returns_array.sort{ |a, b| a[1][:posted_at] <=> b[1][:posted_at]}
```

But ordering with a query is the preferred way:

```
Post.order(:posted_at)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: shorter, more idiomatic, faster: `method_that_returns_array.sort_by { |x| x[1][:posted_at] }`

Comment: Upvote because our CTO came in and implemented the solution this way :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the question that really changes the question, so the first thing that comes to my mind, if the post_ids are sorted correctly is:

```
posts = []

post_ids.each do |post_id|
    posts << Post.find(post_id)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant `posted_at`, not `created_at`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't work because it is a hash inside of an array.

Comment: If you have all of the posts in the database, they will have the created_at timestamp and you can sort it by that. But of course, when you say that you need it sorted by posted_at, that changes everything.

Comment: see the answer, i'm not sure if it will work, but if the post_ids are sorted correctly i think it should.

Comment: Sorry, also corrected the `where` clause to `find`. The `where` would give a collection.